# JQuery function not responsive for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

This has been a very tricky one for me (or I'm just downright dumb). Trying to use a JQuery function to make it that when the user selects a certain radio button, the form below changes accordingly (e.g. an individual sees name, company, title, phone, email and address. company only sees company, phone, email and address. But currently clicking the radio buttons have no effect.

I would also like to ask if: 
1) is my function $('#contactType>input'). in the right place (within the ) or should it be somewhere else? 
2) Could I use a index.js file instead to make it easier? And if so, how to do link the index.js? Is it just

Cheers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  listenForInputChanges();
})

function listenForInputChanges() {
  $('#contactType >input').change(function() {
    console.log('val is ' + $(this).val())
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'individual':
        $('#nameDiv').show();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').show();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;

      case 'team':
        $('#nameDiv').show();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').hide();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;

      case 'company':
        $('#nameDiv').hide();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').hide();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create new contact</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
          <div id="contactType" class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual"> Individual
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team"> Team
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company"> Company</div>
        </div>


        <div id="nameDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="companyDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="comp" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Company" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="titleDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Title" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="phoneDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="int" name="urstel" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Phone" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="emailDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="E-mail" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="addressDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Address" />
          </div>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is working for me

Comment: I just had to add the jQuery lib

Comment: Do you want me to post the answer?

Comment: Where did u copy this from lol

Comment: @bobber205 its a combination of various sources, me meddling and adding to the code and tailoring it a bit to what I need for a contact list.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple different questions in a single SO posting. Your main question is "why doesn't it work", which has been answered. The rest is off topic and derailing your main issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were missing the jQuery lib. Remember to add it in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  listenForInputChanges();
})

function listenForInputChanges() {
  $('#contactType >input').change(function() {
    console.log('val is ' + $(this).val())
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'individual':
        $('#nameDiv').show();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').show();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;

      case 'team':
        $('#nameDiv').show();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').hide();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;

      case 'company':
        $('#nameDiv').hide();
        $('#companyDiv').show();
        $('#titleDiv').hide();
        $('#phoneDiv').show();
        $('#emailDiv').show();
        $('#addressDiv').show();
        break;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create new contact</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
          <div id="contactType" class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual"> Individual
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team"> Team
            <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company"> Company</div>
        </div>


        <div id="nameDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="companyDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="comp" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Company" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="titleDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Title" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="phoneDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="int" name="urstel" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Phone" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="emailDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="E-mail" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="addressDiv" class="form-group">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Address" />
          </div>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you suggest any improvement to that ugly code? Making it simpler? Perhaps using `data-*` attribute?

Comment: You're a legend haha! Working fine now. @RokoC.Buljan it is quite ugly, but its been less than a week of me working with code :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Maybe one or two jajaja. First one of the radio should be preselected. Second i would make a function for each case to make ``listenForInputChanges()`` a little shorter. I wouldnt change the logic. Each programmer has its own logic jajaja

Comment: @kerrysun glas that it helped. Dont forget selecting the answer if it help you

Answer (score 1):

To put your JavaScript in a separate file, just create a javascript file in the same directory as you .html file(For example: 'index.js'). After that put your Javascript that you have made in that file. Now you can include it using script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

src points the path of the index.js file relative to your .html file.

Comment: How does this answers OP's issue?

Comment: He asked if he could put the javascript in a seperate file:
Could I use a index.js file instead to make it easier? And if so, how to do link the index.js? Is it just

Comment: Even if he did it would not help :)

Comment: You're right, but it does answer 1 of his questions.

Comment: Too many questions leads to too many valid answers, where only one is to be chosen. OP broke from SO guidelines. Not your fault Jeroen.